# how to deal with virus coming from removable media like Flash Drive

Tags: windows, windows-xp, backup, usb-flash-drive, anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virus protection for flash drives.](https://superuser.com/questions/32304/virus-protection-for-flash-drives)

I have printing setup where people come to print their documents. The problem is that despite having up-to-date anti-virus that automatically updates itself through internet, the viruses come through removable media like Flash Drive anyway.

I have large amount of data and most of it has been affected, I have tried various anti viruses and when I run them,they do the scanning and detect some viruses, however upon restart, the (`.exe`) file of the anti-virus gets corrupted and many others (`.exe`) as well. The current status is that no anti-virus is being installed.

How do I deal with viruses and save my important data?

OS is Windows XP professional.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an anti-virus boot cd. Something like the [AVG one](http://www.avg.com/gb-en/avg-rescue-cd) (although there are lots of alternatives).

Something like this you can choose to boot from in bios (usually F10 whilst PC is loading) so you can fix before Windows loads up.

EDIT: I'm assuming from your question that your PC is infected already and you can't clean it as anti-virus is being diabled in Windows. If I've misunderstood apologies