# Windows 7: Forbidding executable data on USB device

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, malware

I am concerned that a system could become a Malware vector / Malware hub.  It's a touch screen running Windows 7 that the users can plug their USB Flash Memory into.

I would like to know if there is a way to disallow the copying or running of executable data from any drive other than C.

I assume this would inhibit any Malware migrating from the USB Flash Memory.  Right now my software only needs to read text files from the USB Flash Memory.

Comment: I hope you realize that giving user access to the physical hardware and the running system gives them complete access to everything they could possibly need in attacking that device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virus protection for flash drives](http://superuser.com/questions/32304/virus-protection-for-flash-drives)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Faronics's Anti-Executable software that, basically, blocks execution of software not authorized by you to run. Here: http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/enterprise/anti-executable_en-uk-2/

Comment: Ideally I was looking for a native windows way to do it rather than running some software that only has a 12 month license (this is a kiosk after all).  But since I didn't specify that I'll give you the tick.